# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded (multiple input=file )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

#### HTML

```
<div class="event-image">
  <figure>
    <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/addimg.png'); ?>" />
    <figcaption class="imagcaption">Add Image</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <input type="file" name="upload" />
</div>
```

#### jQuery

```
$(document).on("click","div.event-image",function(){
    $(this).children("input[type=file]").trigger("click");    
});
```

I create above `div` in loop, so there will me many divs with `class="event-image"`. How to trigger the file of the div on which the user click.

Any help would be great

Comment: Because when you triggering input click on document click. Document click automatically calling again and it repeating this process. So you getting this error.

Comment: You can use `e.stopPropagation()` inside click of file

Comment: i am calling document bcz its ajax uploaded div and without it i am not able to click on it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use **`e.stopPropagation()`**

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any
>   parent handlers from being notified of the event.

Add this:

```
$("input[type=file]").on("click", function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
})
```

Comment: i want that when someone click on the div the file upload is triggered

Comment: I know keep your code also just add my lines also. It can solve your error.

Comment: Its working because when you trigger on input `e.stopPropagation()` preventing click on div again.